# How would a species with intangibility-powers deal with war and violence?

Tags: creature-design, warfare, culture, species

I've got an idea for an alien species with intangibility powers, similar to Kitty Pryde from the X-men or Mira Nova and the Tangeans from "Buzz Lightyear of Star Command". They are capable of phasing through solid matter like a ghost, but have to concentrate while using their powers and loud noises and other disturbances will cause them to lose focus, they can only stay intangible for a short amount of time (a few minutes) and if they use their powers for a prolonged period will cause them to deplete their energy. They can also turn objects they touch intangible allowing them to wear clothes while phasing, but nothing too heavy. I'm still undecided if they could turn armor intangible.

Edit: to avoid sinking into the Earth they have an additional power of floating 1 foot above the ground while phasing.

Being capable of turning intangible means that they can phase through physical attacks, and I think this would affect their traditions around violence quite considerably, although they could still murder each other through poison or surprise attacks that are too fast to react to.

Edit:

How would being able to turn intangible affect what kind of tactics they use while fighting a war? And would armor be too much of a disadvantage if they couldn't phase while wearing it, or would it be sufficiently beneficial to use in order to protect from enemy attacks?

The technology level is bronze age to medieval, at least before the large-scale adoption of firearms like muskets and cannons.

Comment: I believe that as stated this question is much too broad, and should be narrowed down to focus on a single aspect of what you are asking. That said, if people can only remain intangible for a few minutes, they should have no issue waging war.

Comment: What will prevent them from becoming intangible with the ground? Otherwise they would fall straight through the ground to the Earth's core. Even if they become intangible to gravity there is a bigger problem. How can you move? You'll be more akin to being in space. You need to have something tangible to push off from. Otherwise you'll have your last momentum and direction, with possibly gravity to pull you. Without solving these issues you'll not use it except in a precious few situations I guess. Going to a floor below as a surprise for example.

Comment: They have additional powers of being capable of floating one foot above the ground.

Comment: That also allows them to give direction I guess? It isn't explicitly in your edit, but that's how I would read it given the conversation.

Comment: Yeah it would. They can move around while phasing. I dont think you should think too much about the scientific implications, just think of the two fictional examples I gave with these powers and how theyre portrayed working.

Comment: What tech level are we talking about here?  If this is "all warfare in all eras" then this is definitely a VTC for being too broad, as @MS indicated.  However,"loud noises and other disturbances will cause them to lose focus" - battlefields are very noisy places, whether it's warcries and screaming in pre-modern times or gunfire and explosions for the last few hundred years.  Ignoring the question of how an intangible being can even detect loud noises, that makes this a non-battlefield power.

Comment: Bronze age to medieval, at least before the widespread adoption of firearms like cannons and muskets.

One thing I realize would affect warfare is that keeping people prisoner would be hard if not impossible, since walls can't hold them.. The prisoner would need to be kept under watch 24/7

Comment: "*would armor be too much of a disadvantage if they couldn't phase while wearing it?*" I believe you'll have to think the other way round : Armor is not something you take on and off casually during a scuffle, so you have to think whether your alien's power is enough to replace armor entirely (hint : it likely won't :) ).

Comment: You specify "intangible" but not "invisible", so lasers would effect them. Also, how much clothing could they take with them? "effecting warfare" is, IMHO, too broad. I believe "The Long War" covers a lot of how this would work.

Comment: Since plate armor weighs between 15-25 kg Im gonna go with around 20 kg as the limit.

Comment: Can two intangible people interact with each-other?

Comment: I havet thought of that, but I guess not since that would defeat the purpose of intangibility.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a War of Assassins, few "battles" as we know them.

The entire point of war, as described by Von Clausewitz, is to get the enemy to submit to what you want them to do. In other words, to impose your political will upon them.

However, it's the most expensive and most disruptive way to impose your will upon them, and tends to have a lot of unanticipated consequences.

So if you can impose your will using other means short of war, it's generally best to do so.

Enter the phasing species: Walls and fortresses won't protect an enemy ruler from assassins and agitators. Assassins and propagandists are MUCH cheaper than a whole army. And they can loot the treasury while there!

So disputes may end before war breaks out.

Example: One king is injured (perhaps killed) by poisons or defenstration or something else suitably kinky...and their realm falls into a succession dispute.

Example: An enemy commander doesn't wake up and their plans mysteriously become public. "*Make Peace!*" posters appear overnight, along with "*The King is a Fink!*" And the funds to pay an army keep vanishing.

Example: Police and Army morale drop as both are subverted by agitators phasing into barracks leaving (or exposing) evidence of corruption, spreading sedition, encouraging insubordination.

So you will get a few senior nobles meeting on a field of battle, more formality than anything else. For them, phasing is an act of submission, though your clever archnemesis will find a way to use phasing for victory instead. That's your fun battle scene. Sorry that it's small.

Answer (score 0):

Ambushes and snipers would become very important:  To allow an attack to phase through you, you must be aware of it.  So, if you want to eliminate someone, surprise is key.  Phasing won't help you if you've had your skull crushed, you're bleeding from a large wound in your throat, or someone has just pulled a knife from your kidneys.  If you're not dead already, you're as good as dead, and if you've phased, no-one will be able to help you.

You can attack while phased: Just put a phased stick through the base of an enemy's skull and unphase it and leave it there.  They're not doing anything with a stick in their brain stem.

Poison the well:  Sending in a phased person with 20kg of poison to dump in the water supplies is a great way to deny an area to your enemies.  You can't phase through poison without phasing through the water you need too.

Defeat in Detail:  If you want to defeat an enemy who knows you're coming, always attempt to apply your numbers against small groups of enemies.  If - or when - they phase, have some of your people phase too if necessary - and for only as long as necessary - and follow them.  When they cannot remain phased any longer, your people can kill them.

Don't bother with armour, it'll only slow you down and tire you out.  Phase when you need to, and unphase as soon as possible.  If you're faced with phased enemies, run away and make a lot of noise to attract assistance.  If you're followed, you can stop and deal with your enemies in detail, starting with the fastest.  Repeat as necessary.

Train to be able to phase fast and for as long as you can and only when you really need to, preferably longer than the enemy.  Whoever gets too tired to remain phased has lost, since they're probably also too tired to fight well unphased.

If loud noises and disturbances can cause a person to unphase, equip your people with loud, harsh noisemakers that they can use to distract the enemy.  Train your own people to be able to remain phased even when surprised and subjected to noise.

As with any military, training is everything, though quantity can have a quality all of its own.

Answer (score 0):

> How would being able to turn intangible affect what kind of tactics
> they use while fighting a war? And would armor be too much of a
> disadvantage if they couldn't phase while wearing it, or would it be
> sufficiently beneficial to use in order to protect from enemy attacks?

They would still need armor, since in a battlefield in the bronze to medieval era they would most likely scream while going at each other's throat, and that would make the intangible ones turn tangible really fast and get dealt with. (assuming they can hear you scream while intangible)

> have to concentrate while using their powers and loud noises and other
> disturbances will cause them to lose focus

The phasing most likely would be affected if they could phase with armor, since armor is pretty heavy and very unfriendly to quick movements.

> They can also turn objects they touch intangible allowing them to wear
> clothes while phasing, but nothing too heavy.

A tactic I can see is a rugged warrior being able to focus for a split second and phasing out of their armor to dodge a cannonball or (if there's any time displacement) reload their musket for a quick shot, which should be incredibly difficult to do with all the noise, the way they create new tactics is relative to how loud a sound has to be to get them to not focus and if after a lot of time fighting they get used to it or desensitized enough not to care about the loud noises.

But the fascinating part lays in their ability to phase for several minutes (bonus points if they turn "invisible"), as that would make espionage and sabotage the common way to win wars, since anyone can phase inside a castle and set it on fire, that could make for some really nice gotcha moments. I don't have any idea as to what could be done to prevent that, maybe they can't phase through a sacred metal or stone, but that's your turn as World Master to decide.